Angular SSR change Meta tag Contant based on Page Api response contant
Angular SSR How to render view by updating meta tag data based on Api response data on routing based (Stirrl+U)
Angular SSR How to render view by updating meta tag update and insert based on Api response data routing based (Stirrl+U)


initialize the MetaTags in your index.html
update your meta Tag as like this.meta.updateTag({name: 'description', content: object.description}); and use Angular Meta for this
for the Title use Angular Title

Check if your SSR runs properly and you're done.
The API call has to happen on Page Initialization
